# Erro no select com PHP + MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, sql-update

Estou tentando usar uma query para puxar um `ID` especifico que vem de outra página.

Eu consigo receber o `ID` por `$_GET`, eu imprimi a query para eu ver se estava certo, mesmo assim da erro e não me mostra qual erro foi.

Código:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dog_house');
    if(!$mysqli)
        die(mysql_error());
    $codigo = $_GET['cod'];
    echo $codigo;//Ver a PK
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `filhotes` WHERE $codigo";
    echo $sql;//Ver a Query
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Update no banco feito";
} else {
    echo "Erro:". $mysqli->error;
}
    ?>
```

Fiz o teste pegando essa query e executando direto no pelo `phpMyAdmin` e funcionou, eu não preciso nesse caso de um array de querys é só uma tupla especifica, mas da erro e `$mysqli->error` não me diz qual o erro.

Comment: `$codigo` tem algo como `codigo = 1` lembre de especificar qual campo quer comparar. Coloca na pergunta um exemplo de como é a saida da query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua query está errada porque não está a comparar $código com nenhum valor. 
Repare:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM filhotes WHERE id_filhotes = '$codigo';
```

**id_filhotes** é a chave primaria da tabela filhotes..inventei esse nome pra voce perceber.. mas nao sei qual a chave primaria da sua tabela... não sei se é com esse valor que voce quer comparar mas é o que faz sentido. O importante é que voce perceba que a sua query esta errada devido ao facto de não comparar nada com o Codigo..

Repare, voce diz: *Selecionar todos os dados da tabela filhotes onde o código.......* e depois nao diz mais nada.... ou seja, voce tem que dizer *Selecionar todos os dados da tabela filhotes onde o "campo da tabela" é igual ao codigo....*....

Boa sorte.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dog_house');
if(!$mysqli)
    die(mysql_error());
$codigo = $_GET['cod'];
echo $codigo;//Ver a PK

//aqui vc deve colocar o nome do campo com PK
//na sua tabela **filhotes** que vc quer comparar com
//o valor da variável $codigo
//veja minha alteração
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `filhotes` WHERE codigo_filhote = '$codigo'";
echo $sql;//Ver a Query
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Update no banco feito";
} else {
    echo "Erro:". $mysqli->error;
}
?>
```